# How to know when children finished parent function call?

Tags: reactjs

I have a form in the parent and dynamically added inputs as child components. On submit I want each child to check its data. Only if there are input-data present and the input data match the data-pattern, the form shall be submitted. Therefore I want to call a child validation from the parent. But how does the parent know when the validation has finished?

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
  validate: function(value) {
    ...
  },

  render: function() {
   return (<Child doValidation={this.state.validationRequest} validate={this.validate}   />);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass another callback function to the child:

```
<Child ... onValidationFinished={this.onValidationFinished} />
```

and the child calls it after the validation:

```
this.props.onValidationFinished()
```

Comment: There might be e.g. 20 Children, how does the parent know that all validation have fnished. It need to count the the validations feedback?

Comment: Or maybe you should consider to extract the validation jobs to the parent, based on your app, the code may be easier to reason about